# Xamarin Master Detail prism Nav bar back button

Tags: xamarin, prism

I have a masterdetailview that uses prism. When I click on one of the menu items the hamburger menu shows up on the nav bar of the new page I clicked and I really just want the top nav bar to show a  back button and be able to go back. How can I achieve this ?
When my app loads I call

```
      await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage");
```

I figured I could call

```
  await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage/InviteFriends");
```

and this would provide the newpage with a back button to Home but when I do this it doesn't do anything

**EDIT**

if I change to

```
  await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage/FeaturePage");
```

which is what the home page will be called(Feature Page) it will not load the page at all.

MainPage is my list of other pages to go to that is shown when the hamburger is pressed if that helps. Feature page is the page I would want to show below the hamburger page and be the "Home" screen.

am I doing that correctly ?

Comment: How is your code when clicking menu items does?

Comment: Like cahyo said, we need more details about the code and screenshot.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT  updated

Comment: @cahyo updated! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if we take your example you have the following Navigation Stack:

> MainPage/NavigationPage

Let's assume your navigation code looks like this in the Master-Detail View Model

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage/InviteFriends");
```

This will lead to the following Navigation Stack:

> /MainPage/NavigationPage/InviteFriends

This is because the navigation was called from the master-detail page.
The master-detail page is considered a root page in Prism and when navigating from a Master-detail page it will set the target page as the detail page of the master-detail.

Check out this article for a more detailed breakdown [Link](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/working-with-masterdetailpages.html#navigating-to-the-masterdetailpage)

**Be careful - Starting with /MainPage will clear the Navigation stack**

One quick solution to this is to add your homepage to the navigation call:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage/NavigationPage/HomePage/InviteFriends");
```

This will create the following:

> MasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/HomePage/InviteFriends

This should hopefully create the response you are looking for.
Hope this helped. Happy coding!

**EDIT:**

I think if you separate your initial Detail Page out into its own file you should then be able to do the following:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage/NavigationPage/HomePage/InviteFriends");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. And I actually have tried this very thing but when I click on the button nothing happens not sure why

Comment: @MicahArmantrout can you supply some snippets of the navigation code?

Comment: I included actual source in my question Just Now

Comment: @MicahArmantrout is your home page inside the detail of the master detail page? or is it in a separate file? your code is just setting the detail page. I'll edit my answer to match your scenario

Comment: no they are in separate pages I updated my question to give more detail

Comment: @MicahArmantrout so in response to your edits i think it should be   await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage/FeaturePage");  for your startup and then when you click the navigation button in the hamburger menu it should be   await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage/FeaturePage/InviteFriends");